# Why do i get this Error :Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '}' at line 27 column 0

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help out in this test class. Why do i get an Error as :

> Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '}' at line 27 column 0.

The test class written is right or do i'm making any mistake? Any help is very much appreciated.

Trigger :

```
trigger ReparentComment on CaseComment (before insert) {
    Map<String, Case> newCaseMap = new Map<String, Case>();
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, List<CaseComment>> ccMap = new Map<Id, List<CaseComment>>();
    for(CaseComment cc : trigger.new)
    {
        caseIds.add(cc.ParentId);
        List<CaseComment> ccList = ccMap.get(cc.ParentId);
        if(ccList == null)
            ccList = new List<CaseComment>();
        ccList.add(cc);
        ccMap.put(cc.ParentId, ccList);
    }
    for(Case c : [Select Id, Subject From Case Where Id in :caseIds Order by CreatedDate])
        if(newCaseMap.containsKey(c.Subject))
            for(CaseComment cc : ccMap.get(c.Id))
                cc.ParentId = newCaseMap.get(c.Subject).Id;
        else
            newCaseMap.put(c.Subject, c);
for(Case c : [Select Id, Subject From Case Where Subject in :newCaseMap.keySet() And Id not in :caseIds And Status != 'Closed'])
    for(CaseComment cc : ccMap.get(newCaseMap.get(c.Subject).Id))
          cc.ParentId = c.Id;
}
```

Test Class :

```
@istest
Public class TestReparentComment{

    static testmethod void testReparentComment(){

        list <CaseComment> casecomment = new list<CaseComment> ();

        {

        CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(commentBody = 'Testing for the comments to appear in the description' ,ParentId = c.Id);

        casecomment.add(cc);

        }

    test.startTest();

    insert casecomment ;

    test.stopTest();

    list <CaseComment> insertedcasecomment = [Select Id ,CommentBody ,ParentId from CaseComment where Id IN :casecpmment ];

    for(CaseComment cc :insertedcasecomment)

    }

}
```

Comment: nikkey - as a frequent poster to SFSE, if Guy's answer was correct (and I believe it is), you should give him the courtesy of accepting the answer so this post can be marked as solved

Answer (score 1):

The { and  } signs in lines 8 and 14 of your test class are incorrect. Remove them and it will work better.